# Angular NVD3 not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to get a basic Angular NVD3 example working. It gets the keys out, but no data/graph. Any ideas why?

The example is copied from here: https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/stackedAreaChart

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.options = {
            "chart": {
                "type": "stackedAreaChart",
                "height": 450,
                "margin": {
                    "top": 20,
                    "right": 20,
                    "bottom": 30,
                    "left": 40
                },
                "useVoronoi": false,
                "clipEdge": true,
                "duration": 100,
                "useInteractiveGuideline": true,
                "xAxis": {
                    "showMaxMin": false
                },
                "yAxis": {},
                "zoom": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "scaleExtent": [
                      1,
                      10
                    ],
                    "useFixedDomain": false,
                    "useNiceScale": false,
                    "horizontalOff": false,
                    "verticalOff": true,
                    "unzoomEventType": "dblclick.zoom"
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                "key": "North America",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 23.041422681023], [1028088000000, 19.854291255832], [1030766400000, 21.02286281168], [1033358400000, 22.093608385173], [1036040400000, 25.108079299458], [1038632400000, 26.982389242348], [1041310800000, 19.828984957662], [1043989200000, 19.914055036294], [1046408400000, 19.436150539916], [1049086800000, 21.558650338602], [1051675200000, 24.395594061773], [1054353600000, 24.747089309384], [1056945600000, 23.491755498807], [1059624000000, 23.376634878164], [1062302400000, 24.581223154533], [1064894400000, 24.922476843538], [1067576400000, 27.357712939042], [1070168400000, 26.503020572593], [1072846800000, 26.658901244878], [1075525200000, 27.065704156445], [1078030800000, 28.735320452588], [1080709200000, 31.572277846319], [1083297600000, 30.932161503638], [1085976000000, 31.627029785554], [1088568000000, 28.728743674232], [1091246400000, 26.858365172675], [1093924800000, 27.279922830032], [1096516800000, 34.408301211324], [1099195200000, 34.794362930439], [1101790800000, 35.609978198951], [1104469200000, 33.574394968037], [1107147600000, 31.979405070598], [1109566800000, 31.19009040297], [1112245200000, 31.083933968994], [1114833600000, 29.668971113185], [1117512000000, 31.490638014379], [1120104000000, 31.818617451128], [1122782400000, 32.960314008183], [1125460800000, 31.313383196209], [1128052800000, 33.125486081852], [1130734800000, 32.791805509149], [1133326800000, 33.506038030366], [1136005200000, 26.96501697216], [1138683600000, 27.38478809681], [1141102800000, 27.371377218209], [1143781200000, 26.309915460827], [1146369600000, 26.425199957518], [1149048000000, 26.823411519396], [1151640000000, 23.850443591587], [1154318400000, 23.158355444054], [1156996800000, 22.998689393695], [1159588800000, 27.9771285113], [1162270800000, 29.073672469719], [1164862800000, 28.587640408904], [1167541200000, 22.788453687637], [1170219600000, 22.429199073597], [1172638800000, 22.324103271052], [1175313600000, 17.558388444187], [1177905600000, 16.769518096208], [1180584000000, 16.214738201301], [1183176000000, 18.729632971229], [1185854400000, 18.814523318847], [1188532800000, 19.789986451358], [1191124800000, 17.070049054933], [1193803200000, 16.121349575716], [1196398800000, 15.141659430091], [1199077200000, 17.175388025297], [1201755600000, 17.286592443522], [1204261200000, 16.323141626568], [1206936000000, 19.231263773952], [1209528000000, 18.446256391095], [1212206400000, 17.822632399764], [1214798400000, 15.53936647598], [1217476800000, 15.255131790217], [1220155200000, 15.660963922592], [1222747200000, 13.254482273698], [1225425600000, 11.920796202299], [1228021200000, 12.122809090924], [1230699600000, 15.691026271393], [1233378000000, 14.720881635107], [1235797200000, 15.387939360044], [1238472000000, 13.765436672228], [1241064000000, 14.631445864799], [1243742400000, 14.292446536221], [1246334400000, 16.170071367017], [1249012800000, 15.948135554337], [1251691200000, 16.612872685134], [1254283200000, 18.778338719091], [1256961600000, 16.756026065421], [1259557200000, 19.385804443146], [1262235600000, 22.950590240168], [1264914000000, 23.61159018141], [1267333200000, 25.708586989581], [1270008000000, 26.883915999885], [1272600000000, 25.893486687065], [1275278400000, 24.678914263176], [1277870400000, 25.937275793024], [1280548800000, 29.461381693838], [1283227200000, 27.357322961861], [1285819200000, 29.057235285673], [1288497600000, 28.549434189386], [1291093200000, 28.506352379724], [1293771600000, 29.449241421598], [1296450000000, 25.796838168807], [1298869200000, 28.740145449188], [1301544000000, 22.091744141872], [1304136000000, 25.07966254541], [1306814400000, 23.674906973064], [1309406400000, 23.418002742929], [1312084800000, 23.24364413887], [1314763200000, 31.591854066817], [1317355200000, 31.497112374114], [1320033600000, 26.67238082043], [1322629200000, 27.297080015495], [1325307600000, 20.174315530051], [1327986000000, 19.631084213898], [1330491600000, 20.366462219461], [1333166400000, 19.284784434185], [1335758400000, 19.157810257624]]
            },

            {
                "key": "Africa",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 7.9356392949025], [1028088000000, 7.4514668527298], [1030766400000, 7.9085410566608], [1033358400000, 5.8996782364764], [1036040400000, 6.0591869346923], [1038632400000, 5.9667815800451], [1041310800000, 8.65528925664], [1043989200000, 8.7690763386254], [1046408400000, 8.6386160387453], [1049086800000, 5.9895557449743], [1051675200000, 6.3840324338159], [1054353600000, 6.5196511461441], [1056945600000, 7.0738618553114], [1059624000000, 6.5745957367133], [1062302400000, 6.4658359184444], [1064894400000, 2.7622758754954], [1067576400000, 2.9794782986241], [1070168400000, 2.8735432712019], [1072846800000, 1.6344817513645], [1075525200000, 1.5869248754883], [1078030800000, 1.7172279157246], [1080709200000, 1.9649927409867], [1083297600000, 2.0261695079196], [1085976000000, 2.0541261923929], [1088568000000, 3.9466318927569], [1091246400000, 3.7826770946089], [1093924800000, 3.9543021004028], [1096516800000, 3.8309891064711], [1099195200000, 3.6340958946166], [1101790800000, 3.5289755762525], [1104469200000, 5.702378559857], [1107147600000, 5.6539569019223], [1109566800000, 5.5449506370392], [1112245200000, 4.7579993280677], [1114833600000, 4.4816139372906], [1117512000000, 4.5965558568606], [1120104000000, 4.3747066116976], [1122782400000, 4.4588822917087], [1125460800000, 4.4460351848286], [1128052800000, 3.7989113035136], [1130734800000, 3.7743883140088], [1133326800000, 3.7727852823828], [1136005200000, 7.2968111448895], [1138683600000, 7.2800122043237], [1141102800000, 7.1187787503354], [1143781200000, 8.351887016482], [1146369600000, 8.4156698763993], [1149048000000, 8.1673298604231], [1151640000000, 5.5132447126042], [1154318400000, 6.1152537710599], [1156996800000, 6.076765091942], [1159588800000, 4.6304473798646], [1162270800000, 4.6301068469402], [1164862800000, 4.3466656309389], [1167541200000, 6.830104897003], [1170219600000, 7.241633040029], [1172638800000, 7.1432372054153], [1175313600000, 10.608942063374], [1177905600000, 10.914964549494], [1180584000000, 10.933223880565], [1183176000000, 8.3457524851265], [1185854400000, 8.1078413081882], [1188532800000, 8.2697185922474], [1191124800000, 8.4742436475968], [1193803200000, 8.4994601179319], [1196398800000, 8.7387319683243], [1199077200000, 6.8829183612895], [1201755600000, 6.984133637885], [1204261200000, 7.0860136043287], [1206936000000, 4.3961787956053], [1209528000000, 3.8699674365231], [1212206400000, 3.6928925238305], [1214798400000, 6.7571718894253], [1217476800000, 6.4367313362344], [1220155200000, 6.4048441521454], [1222747200000, 5.4643833239669], [1225425600000, 5.3150786833374], [1228021200000, 5.3011272612576], [1230699600000, 4.1203601430809], [1233378000000, 4.0881783200525], [1235797200000, 4.1928665957189], [1238472000000, 7.0249415663205], [1241064000000, 7.006530880769], [1243742400000, 6.994835633224], [1246334400000, 6.1220222336254], [1249012800000, 6.1177436137653], [1251691200000, 6.1413396231981], [1254283200000, 4.8046006145874], [1256961600000, 4.6647600660544], [1259557200000, 4.544865006255], [1262235600000, 6.0488249316539], [1264914000000, 6.3188669540206], [1267333200000, 6.5873958262306], [1270008000000, 6.2281189839578], [1272600000000, 5.8948915746059], [1275278400000, 5.5967320482214], [1277870400000, 0.99784432084837], [1280548800000, 1.0950794175359], [1283227200000, 0.94479734407491], [1285819200000, 1.222093988688], [1288497600000, 1.335093106856], [1291093200000, 1.3302565104985], [1293771600000, 1.340824670897], [1296450000000, 0], [1298869200000, 0], [1301544000000, 0], [1304136000000, 0], [1306814400000, 0], [1309406400000, 0], [1312084800000, 0], [1314763200000, 0], [1317355200000, 4.4583692315], [1320033600000, 3.6493043348059], [1322629200000, 3.8610064091761], [1325307600000, 5.5144800685202], [1327986000000, 5.1750695220791], [1330491600000, 5.6710066952691], [1333166400000, 5.5611890039181], [1335758400000, 5.5979368839939]]
            },

            {
                "key": "South America",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 7.9149900245423], [1028088000000, 7.0899888751059], [1030766400000, 7.5996132380614], [1033358400000, 8.2741174301034], [1036040400000, 9.3564460833513], [1038632400000, 9.7066786059904], [1041310800000, 10.213363052343], [1043989200000, 10.285809585273], [1046408400000, 10.222053149228], [1049086800000, 8.6188592137975], [1051675200000, 9.3335447543566], [1054353600000, 8.9312402186628], [1056945600000, 8.1895089343658], [1059624000000, 8.260622135079], [1062302400000, 7.7700786851364], [1064894400000, 7.9907428771318], [1067576400000, 8.7769091865606], [1070168400000, 8.4855077060661], [1072846800000, 9.6277203033655], [1075525200000, 9.9685913452624], [1078030800000, 10.615085181759], [1080709200000, 9.2902488079646], [1083297600000, 8.8610439830061], [1085976000000, 9.1075344931229], [1088568000000, 9.9156737639203], [1091246400000, 9.7826003238782], [1093924800000, 10.55403610555], [1096516800000, 10.926900264097], [1099195200000, 10.903144818736], [1101790800000, 10.862890389067], [1104469200000, 10.64604998964], [1107147600000, 10.042790814087], [1109566800000, 9.7173391591038], [1112245200000, 9.6122415755443], [1114833600000, 9.4337921146562], [1117512000000, 9.814827171183], [1120104000000, 12.059260396788], [1122782400000, 12.139649903873], [1125460800000, 12.281290663822], [1128052800000, 8.8037085409056], [1130734800000, 8.6300618239176], [1133326800000, 9.1225708491432], [1136005200000, 12.988124170836], [1138683600000, 13.356778764353], [1141102800000, 13.611196863271], [1143781200000, 6.8959030061189], [1146369600000, 6.9939633271353], [1149048000000, 6.7241510257676], [1151640000000, 5.5611293669517], [1154318400000, 5.6086488714041], [1156996800000, 5.4962849907033], [1159588800000, 6.9193153169278], [1162270800000, 7.0016334389778], [1164862800000, 6.7865422443273], [1167541200000, 9.0006454225383], [1170219600000, 9.2233916171431], [1172638800000, 8.8929316009479], [1175313600000, 10.345937520404], [1177905600000, 10.075914677026], [1180584000000, 10.089006188111], [1183176000000, 10.598330295008], [1185854400000, 9.9689546533009], [1188532800000, 9.7740580198146], [1191124800000, 10.558483060626], [1193803200000, 9.9314651823603], [1196398800000, 9.3997715873769], [1199077200000, 8.4086493387262], [1201755600000, 8.9698309085926], [1204261200000, 8.2778357995396], [1206936000000, 8.8585045600123], [1209528000000, 8.7013756413322], [1212206400000, 7.7933605469443], [1214798400000, 7.0236183483064], [1217476800000, 6.9873088186829], [1220155200000, 6.8031713070097], [1222747200000, 6.6869531315723], [1225425600000, 6.138256993963], [1228021200000, 5.6434994016354], [1230699600000, 5.495220262512], [1233378000000, 4.6885326869846], [1235797200000, 4.4524349883438], [1238472000000, 5.6766520778185], [1241064000000, 5.7675774480752], [1243742400000, 5.7882863168337], [1246334400000, 7.2666010034924], [1249012800000, 7.5191821322261], [1251691200000, 7.849651451445], [1254283200000, 10.383992037985], [1256961600000, 9.0653691861818], [1259557200000, 9.6705248324159], [1262235600000, 10.856380561349], [1264914000000, 11.27452370892], [1267333200000, 11.754156529088], [1270008000000, 8.2870811422455], [1272600000000, 8.0210264360699], [1275278400000, 7.5375074474865], [1277870400000, 8.3419527338039], [1280548800000, 9.4197471818443], [1283227200000, 8.7321733185797], [1285819200000, 9.6627062648126], [1288497600000, 10.187962234548], [1291093200000, 9.8144201733476], [1293771600000, 10.275723361712], [1296450000000, 16.796066079353], [1298869200000, 17.543254984075], [1301544000000, 16.673660675083], [1304136000000, 17.963944353609], [1306814400000, 16.63774086721], [1309406400000, 15.84857094609], [1312084800000, 14.767303362181], [1314763200000, 24.778452182433], [1317355200000, 18.370353229999], [1320033600000, 15.253137429099], [1322629200000, 14.989600840649], [1325307600000, 16.052539160125], [1327986000000, 16.424390322793], [1330491600000, 17.884020741104], [1333166400000, 18.372698836036], [1335758400000, 18.315881576096]]
            },

            {
                "key": "Asia",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 13.153938631352], [1028088000000, 12.456410521864], [1030766400000, 12.537048663919], [1033358400000, 13.947386398309], [1036040400000, 14.421680682568], [1038632400000, 14.143238262286], [1041310800000, 12.229635347478], [1043989200000, 12.508479916948], [1046408400000, 12.155368409526], [1049086800000, 13.335455563994], [1051675200000, 12.888210138167], [1054353600000, 12.842092790511], [1056945600000, 12.513816474199], [1059624000000, 12.21453674494], [1062302400000, 11.750848343935], [1064894400000, 10.526579636787], [1067576400000, 10.873596086087], [1070168400000, 11.019967131519], [1072846800000, 11.235789380602], [1075525200000, 11.859910850657], [1078030800000, 12.531031616536], [1080709200000, 11.360451067019], [1083297600000, 11.456244780202], [1085976000000, 11.436991407309], [1088568000000, 11.638595744327], [1091246400000, 11.190418301469], [1093924800000, 11.835608007589], [1096516800000, 11.540980244475], [1099195200000, 10.958762325687], [1101790800000, 10.885791159509], [1104469200000, 13.605810720109], [1107147600000, 13.128978067437], [1109566800000, 13.119012086882], [1112245200000, 13.003706129783], [1114833600000, 13.326996807689], [1117512000000, 13.547947991743], [1120104000000, 12.807959646616], [1122782400000, 12.931763821068], [1125460800000, 12.795359993008], [1128052800000, 9.6998935538319], [1130734800000, 9.3473740089131], [1133326800000, 9.36902067716], [1136005200000, 14.258619539875], [1138683600000, 14.21241095603], [1141102800000, 13.973193618249], [1143781200000, 15.218233920664], [1146369600000, 14.382109727451], [1149048000000, 13.894310878491], [1151640000000, 15.593086090031], [1154318400000, 16.244839695189], [1156996800000, 16.017088850647], [1159588800000, 14.183951830057], [1162270800000, 14.148523245696], [1164862800000, 13.424326059971], [1167541200000, 12.974450435754], [1170219600000, 13.232470418021], [1172638800000, 13.318762655574], [1175313600000, 15.961407746104], [1177905600000, 16.287714639805], [1180584000000, 16.24659058389], [1183176000000, 17.564505594808], [1185854400000, 17.872725373164], [1188532800000, 18.018998508756], [1191124800000, 15.584518016602], [1193803200000, 15.480850647182], [1196398800000, 15.699120036985], [1199077200000, 19.184281817226], [1201755600000, 19.691226605205], [1204261200000, 18.982314051293], [1206936000000, 18.707820309008], [1209528000000, 17.459630929759], [1212206400000, 16.500616076782], [1214798400000, 18.086324003978], [1217476800000, 18.929464156259], [1220155200000, 18.233728682084], [1222747200000, 16.315776297325], [1225425600000, 14.632892190251], [1228021200000, 14.667835024479], [1230699600000, 13.946993947309], [1233378000000, 14.394304684398], [1235797200000, 13.724462792967], [1238472000000, 10.930879035807], [1241064000000, 9.8339915513708], [1243742400000, 10.053858541872], [1246334400000, 11.786998438286], [1249012800000, 11.780994901769], [1251691200000, 11.305889670277], [1254283200000, 10.918452290083], [1256961600000, 9.6811395055706], [1259557200000, 10.971529744038], [1262235600000, 13.330210480209], [1264914000000, 14.592637568961], [1267333200000, 14.605329141157], [1270008000000, 13.936853794037], [1272600000000, 12.189480759072], [1275278400000, 11.676151385046], [1277870400000, 13.058852800018], [1280548800000, 13.62891543203], [1283227200000, 13.811107569918], [1285819200000, 13.786494560786], [1288497600000, 14.045162857531], [1291093200000, 13.697412447286], [1293771600000, 13.677681376221], [1296450000000, 19.96151186453], [1298869200000, 21.049198298156], [1301544000000, 22.687631094009], [1304136000000, 25.469010617433], [1306814400000, 24.88379943712], [1309406400000, 24.203843814249], [1312084800000, 22.138760964036], [1314763200000, 16.034636966228], [1317355200000, 15.394958944555], [1320033600000, 12.62564246197], [1322629200000, 12.973735699739], [1325307600000, 15.78601833615], [1327986000000, 15.227368020134], [1330491600000, 15.899752650733], [1333166400000, 15.661317319168], [1335758400000, 15.359891177281]]
            },

            {
                "key": "Europe",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 9.3433263069351], [1028088000000, 8.4583069475546], [1030766400000, 8.0342398154196], [1033358400000, 8.1538966876572], [1036040400000, 10.743604786849], [1038632400000, 12.349366155851], [1041310800000, 10.742682503899], [1043989200000, 11.360983869935], [1046408400000, 11.441336039535], [1049086800000, 10.897508791837], [1051675200000, 11.469101547709], [1054353600000, 12.086311476742], [1056945600000, 8.0697180773504], [1059624000000, 8.2004392233445], [1062302400000, 8.4566434900643], [1064894400000, 7.9565760979059], [1067576400000, 9.3764619255827], [1070168400000, 9.0747664160538], [1072846800000, 10.508939004673], [1075525200000, 10.69936754483], [1078030800000, 10.681562399145], [1080709200000, 13.184786109406], [1083297600000, 12.668213052351], [1085976000000, 13.430509403986], [1088568000000, 12.393086349213], [1091246400000, 11.942374044842], [1093924800000, 12.062227685742], [1096516800000, 11.969974363623], [1099195200000, 12.14374574055], [1101790800000, 12.69422821995], [1104469200000, 9.1235211044692], [1107147600000, 8.758211757584], [1109566800000, 8.8072309258443], [1112245200000, 11.687595946835], [1114833600000, 11.079723082664], [1117512000000, 12.049712896076], [1120104000000, 10.725319428684], [1122782400000, 10.844849996286], [1125460800000, 10.833535488461], [1128052800000, 17.180932407865], [1130734800000, 15.894764896516], [1133326800000, 16.412751299498], [1136005200000, 12.573569093402], [1138683600000, 13.242301508051], [1141102800000, 12.863536342041], [1143781200000, 21.034044171629], [1146369600000, 21.419084618802], [1149048000000, 21.142678863692], [1151640000000, 26.56848967753], [1154318400000, 24.839144939906], [1156996800000, 25.456187462166], [1159588800000, 26.350164502825], [1162270800000, 26.478333205189], [1164862800000, 26.425979547846], [1167541200000, 28.191461582256], [1170219600000, 28.930307448808], [1172638800000, 29.521413891117], [1175313600000, 28.188285966466], [1177905600000, 27.704619625831], [1180584000000, 27.49086242483], [1183176000000, 28.770679721286], [1185854400000, 29.06048067145], [1188532800000, 28.240998844973], [1191124800000, 33.004893194128], [1193803200000, 34.075180359928], [1196398800000, 32.548560664834], [1199077200000, 30.629727432729], [1201755600000, 28.642858788159], [1204261200000, 27.973575227843], [1206936000000, 27.393351882726], [1209528000000, 28.476095288522], [1212206400000, 29.29667866426], [1214798400000, 29.222333802896], [1217476800000, 28.092966093842], [1220155200000, 28.107159262922], [1222747200000, 25.482974832099], [1225425600000, 21.208115993834], [1228021200000, 20.295043095268], [1230699600000, 15.925754618402], [1233378000000, 17.162864628346], [1235797200000, 17.084345773174], [1238472000000, 22.24600710228], [1241064000000, 24.530543998508], [1243742400000, 25.084184918241], [1246334400000, 16.606166527359], [1249012800000, 17.239620011628], [1251691200000, 17.336739127379], [1254283200000, 25.478492475754], [1256961600000, 23.017152085244], [1259557200000, 25.617745423684], [1262235600000, 24.061133998641], [1264914000000, 23.223933318646], [1267333200000, 24.425887263936], [1270008000000, 35.501471156693], [1272600000000, 33.775013878675], [1275278400000, 30.417993630285], [1277870400000, 30.023598978467], [1280548800000, 33.327519522436], [1283227200000, 31.963388450372], [1285819200000, 30.49896723209], [1288497600000, 32.403696817913], [1291093200000, 31.47736071922], [1293771600000, 31.53259666241], [1296450000000, 41.760282761548], [1298869200000, 45.605771243237], [1301544000000, 39.986557966215], [1304136000000, 43.84633051005], [1306814400000, 39.857316881858], [1309406400000, 37.675127768207], [1312084800000, 35.775077970313], [1314763200000, 48.631009702578], [1317355200000, 42.830831754505], [1320033600000, 35.611502589362], [1322629200000, 35.320136981738], [1325307600000, 31.564136901516], [1327986000000, 32.074407502433], [1330491600000, 35.053013769977], [1333166400000, 33.873085184128], [1335758400000, 32.321039427046]]
            },

            {
                "key": "Australia",
                "values": [[1025409600000, 5.1162447683392], [1028088000000, 4.2022848306513], [1030766400000, 4.3543715758736], [1033358400000, 5.4641223667245], [1036040400000, 6.0041275884577], [1038632400000, 6.6050520064486], [1041310800000, 5.0154059912793], [1043989200000, 5.1835708554647], [1046408400000, 5.1142682006164], [1049086800000, 5.0271381717695], [1051675200000, 5.3437782653456], [1054353600000, 5.2105844515767], [1056945600000, 6.552565997799], [1059624000000, 6.9873363581831], [1062302400000, 7.010986789097], [1064894400000, 4.4254242025515], [1067576400000, 4.9613848042174], [1070168400000, 4.8854920484764], [1072846800000, 4.0441111794228], [1075525200000, 4.0219596813179], [1078030800000, 4.3065749225355], [1080709200000, 3.9148434915404], [1083297600000, 3.8659430654512], [1085976000000, 3.9572824600686], [1088568000000, 4.7372190641522], [1091246400000, 4.6871476374455], [1093924800000, 5.0398702564196], [1096516800000, 5.5221787544964], [1099195200000, 5.424646299798], [1101790800000, 5.9240223067349], [1104469200000, 5.9936860983601], [1107147600000, 5.8499523215019], [1109566800000, 6.4149040329325], [1112245200000, 6.4547895561969], [1114833600000, 5.9385382611161], [1117512000000, 6.0486751030592], [1120104000000, 5.23108613838], [1122782400000, 5.5857797121029], [1125460800000, 5.3454665096987], [1128052800000, 5.0439154120119], [1130734800000, 5.054634702913], [1133326800000, 5.3819451380848], [1136005200000, 5.2638869269803], [1138683600000, 5.5806167415681], [1141102800000, 5.4539047069985], [1143781200000, 7.6728842432362], [1146369600000, 7.719946716654], [1149048000000, 8.0144619912942], [1151640000000, 7.942223133434], [1154318400000, 8.3998279827444], [1156996800000, 8.532324572605], [1159588800000, 4.7324285199763], [1162270800000, 4.7402397487697], [1164862800000, 4.9042069355168], [1167541200000, 5.9583963430882], [1170219600000, 6.3693899239171], [1172638800000, 6.261153903813], [1175313600000, 5.3443942184584], [1177905600000, 5.4932111235361], [1180584000000, 5.5747393101109], [1183176000000, 5.3833633060013], [1185854400000, 5.5125898831832], [1188532800000, 5.8116112661327], [1191124800000, 4.3962296939996], [1193803200000, 4.6967663605521], [1196398800000, 4.7963004350914], [1199077200000, 4.1817985183351], [1201755600000, 4.3797643870182], [1204261200000, 4.6966642197965], [1206936000000, 4.3609995132565], [1209528000000, 4.4736290996496], [1212206400000, 4.3749762738128], [1214798400000, 3.3274661194507], [1217476800000, 3.0316184691337], [1220155200000, 2.5718140204728], [1222747200000, 2.7034994044603], [1225425600000, 2.2033786591364], [1228021200000, 1.9850621240805], [1230699600000, 0], [1233378000000, 0], [1235797200000, 0], [1238472000000, 0], [1241064000000, 0], [1243742400000, 0], [1246334400000, 0], [1249012800000, 0], [1251691200000, 0], [1254283200000, 0.44495950017788], [1256961600000, 0.33945469262483], [1259557200000, 0.38348269455195], [1262235600000, 0], [1264914000000, 0], [1267333200000, 0], [1270008000000, 0], [1272600000000, 0], [1275278400000, 0], [1277870400000, 0], [1280548800000, 0], [1283227200000, 0], [1285819200000, 0], [1288497600000, 0], [1291093200000, 0], [1293771600000, 0], [1296450000000, 0.52216435716176], [1298869200000, 0.59275786698454], [1301544000000, 0], [1304136000000, 0], [1306814400000, 0], [1309406400000, 0], [1312084800000, 0], [1314763200000, 0], [1317355200000, 0], [1320033600000, 0], [1322629200000, 0], [1325307600000, 0], [1327986000000, 0], [1330491600000, 0], [1333166400000, 0], [1335758400000, 0]]
            }

        ]

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.9/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css" />
<div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

            <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the generated sample code doesn't have the x & y functions:

```
x: function (d) { return d[0]; },
y: function (d) { return d[1]; },
```

Answer (score 0):

x: function(d){ return d.label; },

```
           y: function(d){ return d.value; },
```

these things are missing in you